# Connect to Ethereum Node using Nodejs

Tags: web3js, nodes, nodejs

I have the following ethereum node running as :

```
sudo geth --rpc --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" --rpcport "8000" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir "/home/Ethereum/Data/node1" --port "30303" --maxpeers 2 --ipcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3,solc" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal" --networkid 1900 --nat "any" --unlock "0" --nodiscover console init ~/Ethereum/Data/node1/customgenesis.json
```

I have installed web3 to connect to this node from nodejs as the following :

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 =Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8000'));
console.log(web3.version.api);
```

but, I am getting this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `new` keyword before `Web3(...`